# Index error with scipy.interpolate.interp1d

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I am trying to get a cubic spline working with the scipy.interpolate.interp1d function. I tried to get the example on the [documentation page](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/tutorial/interpolate.html) working, but whenever I run it I get this error:

> plt.plot(x,y,'o',xnew,f(xnew),'-', xnew, f2(xnew),'--')   File
>   "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/scipy-0.12.0.dev_ddd617d_20120920-py2.7-macosx-10.8-x86_64.egg/scipy/interpolate/interpolate.py",
>   line 396, in **call**
>       y_new = self._call(x_new)   File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/scipy-0.12.0.dev_ddd617d_20120920-py2.7-macosx-10.8-x86_64.egg/scipy/interpolate/interpolate.py",
>   line 372, in _call_spline
>       result = spleval(self._spline,x_new.ravel())   File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/scipy-0.12.0.dev_ddd617d_20120920-py2.7-macosx-10.8-x86_64.egg/scipy/interpolate/interpolate.py",
>   line 835, in spleval
>       res[sl] = _fitpack._bspleval(xx,xj,cvals[sl],k,deriv) IndexError: too many indices

So, it works with the linear interpolation but not with the cubic. I'm probably making some silly error, but I can't figure out what's going wrong. Here is the code for the example that I am using:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.interpolate import interp1d

x = np.linspace(0, 10, 40)
y = np.cos(-x**2/8.0)
f = interp1d(x, y)
f2 = interp1d(x, y, kind='cubic')

xnew = np.linspace(0, 10, 10)
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.plot(x,y,'o',xnew,f(xnew),'-', xnew, f2(xnew),'--')
plt.legend(['data', 'linear', 'cubic'], loc='best')
plt.show()
```

Comment: Your example works ok in my computer, try installing  the stable versions of the packages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Elyase was right. I switched to the Enthought python distribution on my computer – by including "#! /usr/bin/env python" at the top of the script and this made it work. Must be some problem with the scipy version that I was using. Thanks for the quick advice!

Comment: Your script runs fine with scipy 0.12.0 and numpy 1.7.0

Comment: Yeah, now that I checked the versions of numpy and scipy for both python distributions on my computer, I see that it works with scipy 0.12.0 and numpy 1.7.1. It does not work with scipy 0.12.0.dev-ddd617d and 1.8.0.dev-9597b1f. Not sure why I have the crazy development versions, but seems like they got onto the computer somehow...